# Discourage a line break after a certain CJK character with babel

Tags: line-breaking, babel, cjk

When I set Chinese using `babel` and LuaLaTeX, I often find a line break inserted after `：“`. This looks weird to me and I'd prefer the break to come after the `：` and before the `“`.

Can I tweak some `babel` option or TeX setting to discourage this behaviour?

Here's a MWE demonstrating the weird break in the first paragraph and how I'd like it to automatically look in the second paragraph (without manually inserting `\break`).

```
%! TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{chinese-simplified}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}

\hsize 1.85in
魔鬼又带他上了一座最高的山，将世上的万国与万国的荣华都指给他看，对他说：“你若俯伏拜我，我就把这一切都赐给你。”

魔鬼又带他上了一座最高的山，将世上的万国与万国的荣华都指给他看，对他说：\break “你若俯伏拜我，我就把这一切都赐给你。”

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've edited the original answer because there is a better option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main,intraspace=0 .15 0]{chinese-simplified}
\babelfont{rm}{NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf}

\babelcharproperty{`“}{linebreak}{op}
```

This sets the `linebreak` property of “ to ‘opening’, which forbids a line break after this character.

**Original answer**

Perhaps the simplest way is with a transform. It requires a recent version and you may need to increase slightly the `intraspace` (the default value is `0 .1 0`, which is in em units). The following preamble works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main,intraspace=0 .15 0]{chinese-simplified}
\babelfont{rm}{NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf}

\babelprehyphenation{chinese-simplified}{：“}{
  {},  % Keep ：
  {insert, penalty=-100},
  {}   % Keep “
}
```

Comment: Very nice (although I would never have got that from the `babel` docs). Is this something that should be set by default for Chinese in `babel`? I notice XeLaTeX renders my first paragraph the same as the second.

Comment: @DavidPurton  I've opened an issue: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/131 .